# Iframe app redirecting problem during authentication

Tags: iframe

I developed a facebook app with render method as iframe

Now after allowing access, i'm supposed to get a request for permissions dialog box but what i get is a facebook icon with 'go to facebook.com' link at its bottom. If i click the link, i'll be redirected to the request for permissions page.

Someone Plz Help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add the following javascript to your page

```
 <script language=javascript>window.open("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=your_id&redirect_uri=http://your_url", '_parent', '')</script>
```